# How to use MySQL executemany to update list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, list, executemany

I have a list of lists : `myList = [[123, 345], [23, 45], [54, 34]]`

I want to do something like this :

```
cursor.executemany("update tablename set flag = 'yes' where id = %s and officeid = %s", myList)
```

I searched for this and found no solution. If it will never be implemented, what is a better update statement without having to loop through all the elements in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTuples = tuple(map(tuple, myList))

cursor.execute("update tablename set flag = 'yes' \
where (id, officeid) in " + str(myTuples))
```

Comment: It says : TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) but execute() works just fine!

Comment: Thank you - modified the solution above. :)

Comment: How would we modify this if flag is a value in the tuple instead of a constant 'yes'? Can we do : cursor.execute("update tablename set flag = %s \
where (id, officeid) in " + str(myTuples)) where myTuple could be ('nope', 21, 32) .. Any pointers here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
update tablename set flag = 'yes' 
WHERE (id,officeid) IN ((123,345), (23,45), (54,34));
```

Comment: May I know the Python equivalent for a list of lists?

Comment: @ThinkCode: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Python. The query works in Mysql, but I don't know how to pass such parameters in Python.

Comment: Python equivalent for a list of lists is a list of lists. E.g. `myList` in the question is a list of lists. If you made it into a tuple of tuples, it would be `((123,345), (23,45), (54,34))` and interploating it with "%s" would work the way MySQL interpreter expects, though it looks like a venue for an SQL injection if the items come from user input.